# CakePHP Differentiate parent and sub category

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am trying to fetch list in categories and subcategories using same Model. Actually I want list for the select box as Optgroup having parent category and than options as part of optgroup as subcategory.

My structure is..

Category.id, Category.name, Category.parent_id
Through the parent_id I am differentiating parent and child category. Now I wanna list format for the selectbox. I tried this code. Please help me out.

```
    $selectBox = array();
    $conditions =array('Category.status' => '1');
    $category_list = $this->Category->find('all',array('conditions'=>$conditions, 'fields'=>array('Category.id','Category.name','Category.parent_id')));
    foreach ($category_list as $category) {
        foreach ($category['Category'] as $subcategory) {
            $selectBox[$category['Category']['name']][]= array($subcategory['id'] => $subcategory['name']);
          }
    }
    pr($selectBox); exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making use of the framework and not trying to find it out yourself.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html

There is a complete behavior ready for use and it allows also in future to generate more levels of nesting. Also performance wise you might find some differences.